# What does if(!root){ return; } mean in c++

Tags: c++

```
void printCodes(struct MinHeapNode* root, string str)
{
 
    if (!root)
        return;
 
    if (root->data != '$')
        cout << root->data << ": " << str << "\n";
 
    printCodes(root->left, str + "0");
    printCodes(root->right, str + "1");
}
```

Comment: What do you think it does?

Comment: In C++ `struct` is not necessary here.

Comment: It's a shorthand for `root == 0`.    Since `root` is a pointer, and a null pointer constant is one that compares equal with zero,  it is also a shorthand for `root == NULL` or (introduced by C++11 and considered preferable) `root == nullptr`.

Comment: It's a precondition. If the root is `nullptr`, the function will simply return and do nothing.

Comment: @Raildex Also called a "guard condition" or "guard clause". Not sure if C++ has a preferential term for this.

Answer (score 1):

if(root) is equivalent to `if(root != nullptr)`, so `if(!root)` represent `if(root==nullptr)`.

**[!!= -> ==]**

```
 A precondition for almost every recursive function.
```

So when you receive back a `nullptr` root, it means that function reached to the end of the given tree.